# Is there a painless way to run Starcraft 2 on Linux?

Tags: starcraft-2, linux, wine

Now that Starcraft 2 is free to play, is there a painless way to run it in Linux?

People have been doing it with different success for years, but the hacks are spead over different resources and often are distro specific.

I have some specific limitations though.

Since I saw file names like Starcraft64 on a Windows install of Starcraft 2, I would like to run it on a clean 64bit Linux distribution without the multilib 32bit compat layer installed.

I am fine with either 64bit stable wine or the 64bit staging wine, no wrappers like PlayOnLinux or Lutris should be involved.

Is it possible to install and run Starcraft 2 this way?

So far I went to starcraft2.com website and downloaded the installer, but when I ran the file tool on it, I was told it is a 32bit Windows executable, so obviously it won't be able to run under pure 64 wine.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes there is**, and I'm amazed on how easy that is. You can do all installation, download and configuration with flatpack (a similar installer like Ubuntu snaps).

This is the tutorial for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install --install-recommends flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists winepak https://dl.winepak.org/repo/winepak.flatpakrepo
flatpak install winepak com.blizzard.StarCraft2
```

You can also do the same following this [guide](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/jogo-starcraft-ii-no-linux-via-flatpak/) for other distros.

Seat back relax, that's it. After it finishes:

```
flatpak run com.blizzard.StarCraft2
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 it's far from painless. I got *Warning: org.winepak.Platform.Extension.corefonts not installed* during install and thefore running SC2 then throws */app/bin/battlenet-installer: line 21: /app/lib/extension/corefonts/bin/corefonts-install64: No such file or directory*.

Comment: I sort of fixed it by running install of *org.winepak.Platform.Extension.corefonts* which surprisingly works but then the issues continue: I can start it but half of the fonts in the Battle.net app are unreadable (kind of unsurprising considering the install issues related to fonts). I could still manage to download SC2 anyway (I knew what each of the broken buttons say :-)) but when I start SC the resolution is completely screwed. Hopefully, it works better in newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm running this on Linux Mint 19, based on Ubuntu 18. I have the same problems with the fonts. The resolution you just need to fix inside Starcraft settings (if your resolution is not broken enough lol) and set to you screen resolution.

Comment: *update: I have tried to install recently with flatpack but I'm hitting an error in the final step, the 'run' part where the 'Battle.net Launcher.exe' just can't be downloaded. The download starts but errors with connection error in about 18% of download. Curiously if I go to the [blizzard site](https://www.blizzard.com/pt-br/apps/battle.net/desktop), I get the same error trying to download it manually.

Comment: Winepak maintainer has stopped working on the project. Hence this solution does not work anymore.

Comment: `error: Signature made Fri 20 Jul 2018 04:30:34 AM CEST using RSA key ID A959831C080B608F` on second last command, Mint 19.3.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to run the installer and load the battle.net login normally with a 64bit wine prefix, so I think it should work fine.
This was done on Ubuntu 18.04, with wine-4.0-rc2.
As a side note, I did have the multilib 32bit compat layers installed, but I don't know how much that affects 64bit wineprefixes.

Comment: lack of multilib limitation is exactly the show stopper, battle.net is 32bit, according to this forum answer https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20766717149#post-5

Comment: Well, when trying to install wine in ubuntu via http://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu , installing just the amd64 part wasn't enough to get a functional wine setup (no wineserver, only wine64 & wine64-preloader). It had to grab the i386 libs & the i386 part of wine as well. Once it did that, the installer ran. So, I'm thinking there's no good way around this. Installing all of wine, while not fully 64-bit, might be your only way.

Comment: Ubuntu is a multilib distro.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is outdated now. I am now playing sc with the wine version included in ubuntu for years without mayor issue. Probably Blizzard stopped upgrading sc ;-).

Short **answer no**. It takes several ppa/and git repos and the install seems to change from version to version of Starcraft. So it is always painful. I got the current version running and it is playable (4.10.1.75800). I use the internal intel gpu.

What did **not** work for me:

- wine version bundled with the distro (battle net does not even start)
- wine stable version from winehq with vulkan support and wineD3D (battle.net runs but the game crashes with a segmentation fault)

What did work for me

- Purge bundled wine

  ```
    sudo apt purge wine
  ```
- Install wine staging as described [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) from wine-hq (4.14~bionic) with this workaround [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192)
- Install the newest winetricks from github repo

  ```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
  ```
- Install corefonts and d9vk_master via winetricks gui or cli
- Update to the latest ppa version of the mesa vulkan driver (for intel)

  ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers libvulkan1
  ```
- Reboot
- Get the starcraft installer from [here](https://www.blizzard.com/en-us/download) and run it via wine
- I need the nohiz flag to be set to run the game. Otherwise the game crashes after a couple of minutes

  ```
    export INTEL_DEBUG=nohiz; wine start /unix .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Battle.net/Battle.net.exe
  ```
- This issue is probably [fixed](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108914)

Comment: I'm trying to follow the wine-hq instructions; but when I try to install the packages they suggest, I keep getting errors about missing :386 dependencies. How can I install all of those?

Comment: Did you do an: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes I did. It was a message about "package X depends on pacacke Y:i386 but Y:i386 is not going to be installed"; and then if I also mark Y:i386 for installation, it says "package Y:i386 depends on pacacke Z1:i386 and Z2:i386 but they are not going to be installed" etc. etc.

Comment: Followed this answer and installation went a breeze, 64bit prefix on Ubuntu 20.04, Battle.net and StarCraft II all working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm too low-rep to comment, BUT I would like to add to @Erlon r. Cruz's answer that you may be required to install some other packages. To his script (prior to the last step) I had to add:

`flatpak install winepak org.winepak.Platform.Extension.corefonts
flatpak install winepak org.winepak.Platform.Extension.vcrun2015
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-XXX-XX
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform.GL32.nvidia-XXX-XX`

where XXX-XX is the version number of your linux nvidia-driver.

After this I had some minor issues, but they all got fixed in client.

Answer (score 0):

Just to piggy back on @Erlon and @Mark:
This is what I did to make it work:

```
flatpak --user install winepak org.winepak.Platform.Extension.corefonts

flatpak --user install winepak org.winepak.Platform.Extension.vcrun2015

flatpak --user remote-add --no-gpg-verify --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak --user remote-add --no-gpg-verify --if-not-exists winepak https://dl.winepak.org/repo/winepak.flatpakrepo

flatpak --user install winepak com.blizzard.StarCraft2
```

Comment: It seems like the winepak project is dead/unmaintained, and is not installable anymore...

Answer (score -1):

Yeah setup Lutris and will be way easier, first install Wine Staging then Lutris, Lutris will handle the prefix and setup for the game which will make you just click "next next finish".

Lutris.net

Comment: i'm afraid you didn't read the question and didn't pay attention to limitations